# C# For every hour including the time

Tags: c#, datetime, foreach, logic

I am in the process of plotting column chart. Where x axis is the date type

i.e

Day - Plotted in hours

Week - Plotted in Days

Month - Plotted in Weeks

Half Yearly - Plotted in Weeks

Yearly - Plotted in Months

I have a logic like below for plotting graph for Days

```
for (DateTime graphStartDate = startDate; graphStartDate < endDate; graphStartDate = graphStartDate.AddHours(1))
```

for example this is my startdate and end date `10/10/2013 12:00:00 AM` , `10/10/2013 9:32:00 PM`. above code will pick up the graph upto `9:00 PM` only and leave out that 30 minutes ( which is also to be considered). How do i write a loop that will also include that into the calculation.
This has to be implemented for weeks too, as i will be doing `+7` days, there are chances i will leave out `1 - 6` days which is precious information for the end user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Round off EndDate to the next hour/day/month

Example

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(dt);
//hour
Console.WriteLine(dt.AddMinutes(60 - dt.Minute));
//day
Console.WriteLine(dt.AddHours(24 - dt.Hour));
//week
Console.WriteLine(dt.AddDays(7-(int)dt.DayOfWeek));
//month
Console.WriteLine(dt.AddDays(DateTime.DaysInMonth(dt.Year,dt.Month)-dt.Day));
```

Watch out for DayLightSavings

Comment: how does this work for Year, Week and Month. Last line of code is for month ?

Comment: commented the code. Basically you add the difference in hours/minutes so that you will be able too loop through the last one. Hope this gives you an idea